# unpivot list : data type error in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database, sqldatatypes, unpivot

I'm trying to UNPIVOT some columns in the table but having trouble with some of the columns as the datatype is different. So I tried to CAST all columns to VARCHAR(255) but it still doesn't work.

It gives error that:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '' to data type int

I am not sure how is this error occurring when I am converting to varchar and not to int.

Table1 originally has 4 columns c1 , c2 ,c3,c4

```
column - Datatype
c1 - tinyint,
c2-tinyint,
c3-tinyint,
c4-nvarchar(255),

SAMPLE DATA:
c1 : 1,
c2:1,
c3:0,
c4:'Profit'
```

Need to combine multiple columns into one column hence using unpivot

```
SELECT *
     FROM 
       (select
        ,CAST([c1] AS varchar(255)) AS[c1]
        ,CAST([c2] AS varchar(255)) AS[c2]
         ,CAST([c3] AS varchar(255)) AS[c3]
          ,CAST([c4] AS varchar(255)) AS[c4]
    from table1)a
    
        UNPIVOT ([set] FOR [sets] IN ([c1],[c2],[c3],[c4])
```

> Error : "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'profit' to data type int."

Comment: Where is PROFIT coming from ?

Comment: yes it should work but i am still getting this error 
"Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'profit' to data type int."

Comment: Are you trying to push the results into another table where SET is an INT ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Select *
 From (
        Select CAST([c1] AS varchar(255)) AS[c1]
              ,CAST([c2] AS varchar(255)) AS[c2]
              ,CAST([c3] AS varchar(255)) AS[c3]
              ,CAST([c4] AS varchar(255)) AS[c4] 
          from table1
  ) A
unpivot ([set] FOR [sets] IN ([c1],[c2],[c3],[c4]) ) unp
```

Results

```
set     sets
1       c1
1       c2
0       c3
Profit  c4
```

**EDIT**

Not clear where the error is coming from, but here is a dynamic UNPIVOT without using Dynamic SQL and no need to convert datatypes.

```
Select B.*
 From  table1 A
 Cross Apply (
              Select [Key]
                    ,Value
               From OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES  )) 
             ) B
```